# Find closest index of array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, find, closest

I have the following function:

```
(function(){
    function closest (num, arr) {
        var curr = arr[0];
        var diff = Math.abs (num - curr);
        for (var val = 0; val < arr.length; val++) {
            var newdiff = Math.abs (num - arr[val]);
            if (newdiff < diff) {
                diff = newdiff;
                curr = arr[val];
            }
        }
        return curr;
    }
    var _array = [2, 42, 82, 122, 162, 202, 242, 282, 322, 362],
        _number = 155;

    return closest (_number, _array);
})()
```

`Result is 162`

---

In this array I want to show the closest index to the result!
`The result should be number 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the index and return this value.

```js
function closest(num, arr) {
    var curr = arr[0],
        diff = Math.abs(num - curr),
        index = 0;

    for (var val = 0; val < arr.length; val++) {
        let newdiff = Math.abs(num - arr[val]);
        if (newdiff < diff) {
            diff = newdiff;
            curr = arr[val];
            index = val;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

var array = [2, 42, 82, 122, 162, 202, 242, 282, 322, 362],
    number = 155;

console.log(closest(number, array));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more straightforward solution (not optimal):

1. find the difference between the number and the numbers in the array
2. find the minimum in the new array of differences
3. Now find the index of that minimum

```js
var _array = [2, 42, 82, 122, 162, 202, 242, 282, 322, 362],
  _number = 155;

// closest index?

const diffArr = _array.map(x => Math.abs(_number - x));
const minNumber = Math.min(...diffArr);
const index = diffArr.findIndex(x => x === minNumber);

console.log('Result index', index);
```