# Return value from an array based on input that fits between two steps of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I start off with two arrays like this

```js
const colors = ["#00876c", "#50a26f", "#88bb72", "#c1d379", "#fde987", "#fac067", "#f49654", "#e86b4e", "#d43d51"];
const steps  = [13.5, 13.6875, 13.875, 14.0625, 14.25, 14.4375, 14.625, 14.8125, 15];
```

Both the `colors` array and `steps` array have the same length, so you can interpret it as each step associating with the color at the given index.

What I'm trying to do is, based on the value of an input, fit it between the steps and associate said input with its color.

For example:

```js
returnColor(13.2) // returns #00876c
returnColor(20)   // returns #d43d51
returnColor(13.7) // returns #50a26f
returnColor(14.5) // returns #fac067
```

Feel free to ask any question if I haven't explained quite well.

Comment: Are you sure your examples are correct.  If I've understood your question properly, then your third and fourth examples are off-by-one.  13.7 should be #88bb72 and 14.5 should be #f49654.
Unless Philip F. below has nailed it.

Comment: 13.7 fits between 13.6875 and 13.875 so its associated color should be #50a26f.
14.5 fits between 14.4375 and 14.625 so its associated color should be #fac067

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the closest function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028904/find-closest-index-of-array-in-javascript) to get the index which is most similar to the input provided.

```js
const colors = ["#00876c", "#50a26f", "#88bb72", "#c1d379", "#fde987", "#fac067", "#f49654", "#e86b4e", "#d43d51"];
const steps  = [13.5, 13.6875, 13.875, 14.0625, 14.25, 14.4375, 14.625, 14.8125, 15];

//get the index of the element which is closest to the step
function closest(num, arr) {
    var curr = arr[0],
        diff = Math.abs(num - curr),
        index = 0;

    for (var val = 0; val < arr.length; val++) {
        let newdiff = Math.abs(num - arr[val]);
        if (newdiff < diff) {
            diff = newdiff;
            curr = arr[val];
            index = val;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

function returnColor(step) {
  const index = closest(step, steps);
  return colors[index];
}

//Tests
console.log(returnColor(13.2)); // returns #00876c
console.log(returnColor(20));   // returns #d43d51
console.log(returnColor(13.7)); // returns #50a26f
console.log(returnColor(14.5)); // returns #fac067
```

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as I want it!